# SSIS can't read end of column in excel file (Excel Connection Manager)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I've got a problem when SSIS can't read end of column in excel file like following below (Presort id) :
[image: Excel File]

[image: SSIS Excel Source Editor]

I have tried to figure out by edit OpenRowSet for Excel Source (Data Flow), but it still not working.

[image: Excel Source Custom Properties - OpenRowSet]

[image]

My temporary workaround is should to click 'Enable Editing' button on each excel files and then [Presort Id] column successfully read.

My goal for this issue is [Presort ID] column should read by SSIS, instead each of excel files in Protected mode.

Please kindly give any idea to fix this problem.
Thank you...

Comment: what if you click on "Enable Editing" and save the doc and try again?

Comment: It works....but it will be wasting time if you should to open more than 100 files like that... :(

Comment: so try disable tahe security feature and the file will be enabled for editing by default. look at this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/enable-editing-by-default/112b0038-fe3e-4e84-b868-c470b06aad93

Comment: @Flicker i think this should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Microsoft office security options, you have to unckeck all **Protected Mode Options** from the office trust center.

The following link contains a step-by-step guide to do that:

- [How to Turn Off “Enable Editing” in Microsoft Office 2010](https://www.thrivenetworks.com/blog/turn-off-enable-editing-office-2010/)

Comment: I have tried that way, but the SSIS still has facing error about VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA. Instead I have disable "Enable Editing" on Trust Center, I should to open each excel files and then save it. After that SSIS can read the column and work properly. :(

Comment: @AfifPratama if you are facing `VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA` then just delete the Excel connection manager and recreate it Or just disable the Excel source `ValidateExternalMetadata` property